# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f '\bar{f}'+x^2 f\bar{f}dx\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f|^2 dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose complex function $f$ in the Schwartz Space, its definition see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space how can we argue that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f '\bar{f}'+x^2 f\bar{f}dx\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f|^2 dx ~?$$
PS: $\bar{f}$ is conjugate to $f$, $f'=\frac{df}{dx}.$

I try to integrate by parts, but I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 
$$|f'(x)+xf(x)|^2=|f'(x)|^2+x^2|f(x)|^2+xf(x)\overline{f'(x)}+x\overline{f(x)}f'(x),$$
then integrate by parts in the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)\overline{f'(x)}dx$.

Comment: U r correct, Thanks! Btw, how can you think that it could be solved in this way?

Comment: The integrand in the RHS reminds the square of the modulus of $f'(x)+xf(x)$.